# Не работают WebSockets на HTTPS

Tags: node.js, websocket, ssl, https

Недавно перевел сервер на HTTPS, после перехода перестали работать WebSockets.

На клиенте был изменен протокол с ws на wss. На сервере (работает на NODE JS) также были подключены файлы сертификатов и выполнены необходимые настройки. В результате сейчас на клиентах вываливается ошибка:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:4433/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled
```

Код серверной части на Node JS:

```
var https = require('https');
var WebSocketServer = require('ws'), fs = require('fs');
var port = 4433; 
var app = null;

var processRequest = function( req, res ) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("All glory to WebSockets!\n");
};

app = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/ssl/server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/ssl/bundle.crt'),
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
}, processRequest ).listen(port);

var webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer.Server( { server: app } );
```

Как подружить Websockets с HTTPS?

Comment: Зачем вам `requestCert`?

Comment: @andreymal в настройке ssl не очень большой опыт, поэтому взял конфигурацию из примера на этом сайте (где обсуждался схожий вопрос).

Comment: @andreymal а можно где-нибудь посмотреть более детальную выдачу по какой причине не происходит обмен "рукопожатиями" между браузером и сервером?

Comment: @andreyma спасибо!!! удалил requestCert из настроек и все нормально заработало

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как оказалось, в этой проблеме было целых 2 нюанса:

- первый заключался в адресе обращения к wss. вместо IP-адреса надо было  использовать имя домена на который выдавались сертификаты. (спасибо @bingo347 с toster.ru)
- второй в том, что необходимо было убрать из настроек подключения "requestCert: true" (спасибо @andreyma).